# How to 'do' (and USE) HTML Bundles (from Web Essentials) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-essentials

According to the [Web Essentials Web Site](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html):

> Bundle HTML
>
> Select 2 or more HTML files in Solution Explorer, then
>   right-click and select Create HTML Bundle File.
>
> This feature makes it easy to bundle multiple HTML templates for use
>   in SPA's.

Now, experimenting I find that bundling HTML files does exactly what I would expect...concatenates the selected files...ok..

However, I do not SEE (nor can I find it documented anywhere...) how to tell an external resource (an angularjs directive, for instance) which html fragment the controller should "use". I might expect something like:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('My_App')
        .directive('myHeaderDtv', myHeaderDtv);

    myHeaderDtv.$inject = ['$window'];

    function myHeaderDtv($window) {
        // Usage:
        //     <cmr-header-dtv></cmr-header-dtv>
        // Creates:
        //      Uniform page header for CMR web pages.
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: { user: '=' },
            templateUrl: 'App/HeaderView.html' //the template only file
                             //should be replaced with...
            templateUrl: 'App/MyBundle.html.header'
                          // fileName: MyBundle.html
                          // template's parent html element: <header>

        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    }

})();
```

When the bundled HTML file (myBundle.html) looks something like:

```
<header>
...
</header>

<footer>
...
</footer>
```

*...or perhaps something in bundling process that wraps each selected file with some javascript to 'declare' that "this is a template named 'header'...*

In short: how does an angularjs directive find it's html template from within a bundle?

(note: I have already Google'd the heck out of this and can't find any examples of someone using an html bundle)

Answer (score 1):

I think this Blog post is covering what we need to use Html bundling within Visual Studio in a way that can be consumed by Angular.

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/18/asp-angular-optimisation.html